# i want to make my server in python socket online for every one in the world not just for my network home

Tags: python, sockets

The question is that I am working on a messaging program in Python and it works, but only on my home network. I want it to work on an online level for my friends, and I was working on the program with Python socket. I hope you understand the question

```
import socket
import threading


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_l = conn.recv(HEADER).decode('utf-8')
        if msg_l:
            msg_l = int(msg_l)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_l).decode('utf-8')
            if msg == DISCONNECT:
                connected = False

            msg_of_client = (f"{addr} : {msg}")  # the message of client
            print(msg_of_client)
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: Sorry for the weird question, but I don't know how to use Stack Overflow

Comment: its fine -- we can only help you as long as you are asking a question -- right now, there is no question in your post -- if you want to ask "why isn't my code segment working", then include that in your post and also inclue what the code is outputing and what you want it to output

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: It is nothing related to `tkinter`.  What you need is a server that can be accessed by others via internet.

Comment: The question is that I am working on a messaging program in Python and it works, but only on my home network. I want it to work on an online level for my friends, and I was working on the program with Python socket. I hope you understand the question

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

Comment: Please wait until OP edits their question to actually include a question instead of writing an asnwer.